# Trouble indexing MySQLi object in PHP

Tags: php, mysqli

I am able to successfully iterate through said MySQLi object in a foreach loop like so:

```
// Retrieving accounts
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM accounts");
$stmt->execute();
$accounts = $stmt->get_result();

// Iterating over object
foreach ($accounts as $account) {
    print_r($account);
}
```

...hence, I thought this would work, too:

```
print_r($accounts[0]);
```

...but it doesn't, as I receive this error message:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot use object of type mysqli_result as array

Does anyone know how I would correctly index a MySQLi object similar to what I'm trying, if possible?

Comment: I know that PDO has a fetchAll() method that retrieves all rows into an array, but I'm not sure if mysqli has the same thing. Could you modify your `foreach()` to include the index? `foreach ($accounts as $key => $account)` for example? You get that error because, as it says, the results object is an object, not an array.

Comment: @droopsnoot I added `->fetch_all()` to `get_result()` and it worked. Thank you for the suggestion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved my issue by simply changing

```
$accounts = $stmt->get_result();
```

to

```
$accounts = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_all();
```

in the first code sample

Answer (score 1):

Although PHP's primary collection is an array, it also supports custom collections using an object through the [Iterator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.iterator.php) and [Traversable](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.traversable.php) interfaces. The latter interface is not intended for user-land code, but core and extensions can use it and implement their own logic, and that's what [`get_result`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php) actually does. That interface also doesn't give any actual methods, it is just an identifier basically for the `foreach` construct:

> Internal (built-in) classes that implement this interface can be used in a foreach construct and do not need to implement IteratorAggregate or Iterator.

If mysqli had supported Iterator instead, you would have access to key-based indexes, but I'm guessing they really didn't make sense for mysql to do.